# Fetch json field value from curl response in github action

Tags: json, github, curl, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have the below curl request and also attached the response from the response I need to extract the value for "status.azure.resource_name" I'm new to GitHub action so stuck with this issue from more than 8 hours please help on this if it is in some programming languages I would have resolved by now

Curl request:

```
curl --location --request PUT $URL \
                                          --header "$AUTH_HEADER" \
                                          --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
                                          --data-raw "$PAYLOAD)"
```

And the response:

```
{
  "labels": {},
  "spec": {
    "mysql": {
      "version": "8.0",
      "sku": {
        "name": "GP_Gen5_4"
      },
      "storage_profile": {
        "storage_mb": 5120
      }
    },
    "key_vault": {
      "access_policies": [
        {
          "name": "test",
          "type": "group",
          "project": null
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "type": "azure-mysql",
  "name": "mysql",
  "id": "1234",
  "created_at": "2012-03-04T10:00:05+00:00",
  "updated_at": "2012-03-04T10:00:05+00:00",
  "project": {
    "id": "ae3dfa99",
    "name": "Test",
    "url": "www.google.com",
    "geography": "in"
  },
  "links": {
    "key_vault": {
      "endpoint": {
        "url": "",
        "description": "test.",
        "display_name": "test"
      },
      "azure_portal": {
        "url": "test",
        "description": "Link to the resource in the Azure portal.",
        "display_name": "Key Vault Azure Portal"
      }
    },
    "azure_portal": {
      "url": "test",
      "description": "Link to the resource in the Azure portal.",
      "display_name": "Azure Portal"
    },
    "endpoint": {
      "url": "test",
      "description": "Azure resource endpoint.",
      "display_name": "test"
    }
  },
  "url": "test",
  "tags": {
    "cost_center_id": "471000",
    "customer": "internal",
    "product_group": "internal",
    "environment_type": "test",
    "budget_category": "",
    "team": ""
  },
  "spiffe_id": "test",
  "status": {
    "ready": false,
    "state": "reconciling",
    "deployment": {
      "steps": {}
    },
    "azure": {
      "resource_name": "test",
      "id": null,
      "subscription_id": "test",
      "resource_group": "test"
    },
    "key_vault": {
      "access_policies": []
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `jq` to do the json parsing. It is already available [in the github action runner](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2004-Readme.md#tools).

In your case it would be like this (I pasted your response json into `test.json` file)

```
$ cat test.json | jq .status.azure.resource_name
"test"
```